# imap_fetchstructure() doesn't return the parts object

Tags: php, imap

I have a problem in imap_fetchstructure($this->stream,$messageNumber).
some email used is working perfectly and another email is not working, the problem is: the parts object is missing in the structure.

as i said some gmail account the code working perfectly and the one which i have to use not working to fetch the message structure. but mail info, header i got without problem, the problem is if i call this function

$msg  =  $imap->returnEmailMessageArr($val['msgno']);

//after that this function is called

private function returnMessageStructureObj($messageNumber){

```
    return imap_fetchstructure($this->stream,$messageNumber);
}
```

for that gmail account which is not fetching the parts object ,the structure is as following :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => 0
    [encoding] => 4
    [ifsubtype] => 1
    [subtype] => HTML
    [ifdescription] => 0
    [ifid] => 0
    [lines] => 166
    [bytes] => 9904
    [ifdisposition] => 0
    [ifdparameters] => 0
    [ifparameters] => 0
    [parameters] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

)
```

Please help me to find that problem thanks a lot

Comment: A single-part message would not have "parts", would it?

Answer (score 1):

A message with a `->type` of `0` is defined as `text` and will have no parts.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and i resolved by using below code, i only need to fetch body of the mail
Where $val is the UID or you can also use message_no

```
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($connection,$val,FT_UID);
if($structure->type!=0)
{
$data = imap_fetchbody($connection,$val,1,FT_UID);
    if ($structure->encoding==4)
        $data = quoted_printable_decode($data);
    elseif ($structure->encoding==3)
        $data = base64_decode($data);
    if (strtolower($structure->subtype)=='plain')
       $plainmsg .= trim($data) ."\n\n";
    else
    $htmlmsg .= $data ."<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: I got this error:- `PHP Warning:  imap_fetchstructure(): UID does not exist in`